# Combobox to sync selected value

Tags: c#, winforms

The following code is populating my combo box with values

```
List<Filename> fnList = new List<Filename>();
fnList.Add(new Filename("test1.png"));
fnList.Add(new Filename("test2.png"));
fnList.Add(new Filename("test3.jpg"));
comboBox1.DataSource = fnList;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Now the code below is supposed to sync selected value with the member in associated object.

```
comboBox1.DataBindings.Clear();
comboBox1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", copy, "EventPicture");
```

`copy` is of some class, where `EventPicture` is string Property. This is where I want to have selected value synced every time user change combo box selection AND every time `EventPicture` value is changed from other parts of code.

At this point I'm getting an error:

`Cannot set the SelectedValue in a ListControl with an empty ValueMember.`

Comment: Have you tried setting the `ValueMember` on the combo box?

Comment: ahh, that quickly addressed the issue and now sync works :) How I could miss that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `ValueMember` on the ComboBox as well.

```
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Name";
```